# how to make a <div> column that stretches to height of two <div>s beside it?

Tags: html, css

Goal: In the content area of a site, I need to make a decorative-only column that spans the height of two divs (containing images) beside it.

Problem: the column either has no height, regardless which attributes I give it, or only has the height of the first sibling div and no fill.  I have tried height: 100%, min-height: 100%. Also tried making parent  position: absolute and setting top: 0 and bottom: 0.

the code:

```css
.row {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: #000 3px dashed;
}
#colLeft {
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
#B1 {
    float: left;
    width: 84%;
    height: 100px;  /* this will actually be the height of the img */
    background-color: green;
 }
 #B2 {
     width: 84%;
     height: 100px;  /* this will actually be the height of the img */
     float: left;
     background-color: #ff0;
 }
```

```html
    <div class="row">
        <div id="colLeft"></div>
        <div id="B1">
            <img src="foo">
        </div>
        <div id="B2">
            <img src="bar">
        </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

what I want:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgr5g.png
What I get:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/lS63m.png

Comment: does this helps you? http://jsfiddle.net/ajat1ppm/ if so I'll explain in an answer what went wrong if you like

Comment: if you float think about clearing aswell: https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: @caramba - thank you.  I understand what you did, and why it works for a fixed viewport (making the left-hand part of the row appear to be the column.)  However, the reason I want the column to be its own div, is so that I can collapse it later, when the viewport gets smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the left column to `position: absolute`.

```css
.row {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: #000 3px dashed;
}
#colLeft {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
#B1 {
    float: right;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}
#B2 {
     width: 80%;
     height: 100px;
     float: right;
     background-color: #ff0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <div id="colLeft"></div>
        <div id="B1">
            <img src="foo">
        </div>
        <div id="B2">
            <img src="bar">
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why `z-index`? also the code on code pen is not the same as here

Comment: @netzzwerg - vielen Dank!  that works (code on code pen.)  I did think about doing it that way, but thought there must be some way to do it with left floats.  I still do not understand at what point an empty div gets layout.

Comment: @diver864 gerne. Look at [this link](http://marksheet.io/css-box-model.html) for more details about css layout rendering.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have `height: 100px;  /* this will actually be the height of the img */` for both `img` in your `.row`

You can do it like this also, fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/QwZuf/260/

in this example I set the height of **200px** to the row and height of **100%** to the column

```
.row {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: #000 3px dashed;
    height: 200px;
}
#colLeft {
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: thanks, that worked, too.  I just thought there should be some way to have the column stretch to fit, rather than explicitly having to give it a height in pixels.  Trying to make the design 'fluid' enough to be reusable, where the image sizes might change.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate solution I found that works very well, too.

```
.row {
    display: table-row;
}
#colLeft {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 15%;
    background-color: red;
}
#B1 {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 84%;
    height: auto; 
    background-color: green;
 }
 #B2 {
     display: table-cell;
     width: 84%;
     height: auto;
     background-color: #ff0;
 }
```